# How to Accessing .vbs file in Firefox and Chrome Browser Using Html

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vbscript, activex

Am Calling Notepad.vbs File In IE Browser... It Works

The Notepad.vbs Contains

```
Dim obj
Set obj = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
obj.Exec("notepad.exe")
Set obj = Nothing
```

How To Executing This Notepad.vbs In FireFox and Chrome Browser....?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vb script not working on chrome, or firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624328/vb-script-not-working-on-chrome-or-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

CreateObject is ActiveX technology. It's supperted only in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever browser we can **run** the **vbs script file** using **ASP** (Server Side Script)

***(I.E.,):***

```
<%
 Dim obj
 Set obj = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
 obj.Exec("notepad.exe")
 Set obj = Nothing
%>
```